# Django rest framework custom filter - order search by children count

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I use [DRF](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/tree/master) with [django-rest-framework-filters](https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters) .

Models are: Order that has many OrderItems. Task is to create filter, that enable to search orders by order items count or sort by count.

in my view.py :

```
class OrderFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    order_items_count = filters.NumberFilter(name="order_items__count")
    customer = filters.RelatedFilter(
        CustomerFilter,
        name='customer',
        queryset=Customer.objects.all(),
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = {
            'internal_code': ['icontains'],
            'notes': ['icontains'],
            'status': ['exact'],
            'complete': ['exact'],
            'order_items_count': ['exact']
            }

class OrderViewSet(BaseViewSet, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    filter_class = OrderFilter
    filter_backends = (
        OrderingFilter,
        DjangoFilterBackend,
        )
    ordering_fields = (
        'internal_code',
        'notes',
        'status',
        'complete',
        'customer__title',
        'order_items__count',
        )
```

On request `/orders?order_items_count=2` I got error:
Related Field got invalid lookup: count

How can I create custom filter for count of model's children? Thank you.

P.S. It's my first question on stackowerflow, sorry for style errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First change your queryset on the view set to:

`queryset = Order.objects.annotate(order_items_count=Count('order_items')).all()`

this will make sure the queryset has the field `order_items_count`

use this as your `order_items_count` filter

```
order_items_count = filters.NumberFilter(method='filter_orders_by_item_count')

def filter_orders_by_item_count(self, queryset, name, value):
    return queryset.filter(order_items_count=value)
```

for ordering on a non-model field use a custom ordering filter as described in link [1]

the filter method on custom filter will be:

```
def filter(self, qs, value):
        # OrderingFilter is CSV-based, so `value` is a list
        if any(v in ['order_items_count', '-order_items_count'] for v in value):
            return queryset.order_by(value)
        return super(CustomOrderingFilter, self).filter(qs, value)
```

[1] https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html?highlight=custom#adding-custom-filter-choices